# filtering dropdown values in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='Foo_picks', unique=True)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In Django admin add_view:

```
def add_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.exclude = ("added_on",)
    self.readonly_fields = ()
    return super(Bar, self).add_view(*args, **kwargs)
```

So, Field shows in the admin add view is `foo` Which is a drop down list and shows all the titles. Some `title` of `Foo` remains empty or ''. So, drop down list have lots of empty value because it title is empty. I want to filter out those empty values.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can provide your own form for ModelAdmin, with custom queryset for foo field.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

#Create custom form with specific queryset:
class CustomBarModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomBarModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo'].queryset = Foo.objects.filter(title__isnull=False)# or something else

# Use it in your modelAdmin
class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomBarModelForm
```

Something like this...

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin)

Comment: how do you filter using the model's attributes?

Comment: Note, this only effects the dropdown values on the change page, not the filters on the changelist page.

Comment: There is get_changelist_form method for this

Comment: for django 1.8+, add `fields` attribute to meta class like `fields = '__all__'`

Comment: How do you filter based on a value that is inserted in another admin field?

Answer (score 21):

for django 1.6:

For foreign key:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "title":
        kwargs["queryset"] = Foo.objects.filter(title__isnull=False)
    return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is the appropriate answer

Comment: Link is no longer valid.

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Comment: Works in 3.1.4 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Still works, (currently) most recent docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Comment: Surprisingly it's working on Django 3.2 thank you!

Comment: Still works with django 4.0: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this question when looking for a solution to filter **dropdown options on the fly** in the admin interface based on the **selection in another field** -- not based on a pre-filtered list at page load.  The solution I found was this library:  https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects which is an app that uses ajax calls and allows chain filtering to multiple levels.  Works like a charm for me. -HTH

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass your own model.ModelAdmin and create a custom field for your ChoiceField...

```
class CustomForm(model.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo

    foo = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, initial=self.foo_queryset)

    def foo_queryset(self):
        return Foo.objects.filter(xy)...

class FooAdmin(model.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomForm
```

Comment: There is no `self` in the context of field definitions