# Adding data in django admin filtering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Hi I have 3 models in my django. Product, Client, and Order.

```
Class Client(models.Model):
 name = ...
 ....

Class Product(models.Model):
 name = ...
 client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
 .....

Class Order(models.Model):
 qty = ...
 created = ...
 customer_name = ...
 ...
 ...
 client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
 product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

admin.py

```
    class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        pass

    admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

the flow of my project is that, I have so many `Clients` and each of them have so many `products`. So when there is an `Order`, I specify the `Clients` and the `product` of the order.

my problem is this, in my Admin page, when I add an `Order`, select a particular `client` and when I scroll down the `Product` field, it will show all the lists of `products`.

my question is that, is it possible that in admin page,in adding an `Order` when I scroll the `Product`, it will show only the `Product` lists of the `client` that I have selected? and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible and fairly well documented. Here is the official documentation: [custom validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin). This might also help: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581520/filtering-dropdown-values-in-django-admin)