# Exclude one Field value in Foreign Key dropdown list in Model Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model like this:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    package_price = models.IntegerField()

class UserPackage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package)
```

ModelForm like this:

```
class UserPackageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPackage
        exclude = ['user']
```

I want to list the `packages` excluding `Free` that's why I am doing like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserPackageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['package'].queryset = Package.objects.exclude(package="Free")
```

It is showing `Free` package too. What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filtering dropdown values in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581520/filtering-dropdown-values-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 3):

exclude argument is wrong, try package_name instead of package.

```
from django.forms.models import BaseModelFormSet

class UserPackageForm(ModelForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserPackageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['package_name'].queryset = self.fields['package_name '].queryset.exclude(package_name="Free")
```

Comment: also make a change to __init__ function. use self.queryset

Comment: hopfully the last change I made will do the trick.self.fields['package_name'].queryset = self.fields['package_name '].queryset.exclude(package_name="Free")

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`self.fields['package'].queryset = Package.objects.exclude(package__name="Free")`