# Model require to add star-ratings class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-ratings

I added django-star-ratings to my Django project, so I have in models.py this field:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    rating = models.ForeignKey('star_ratings.Rating')
```

and in template:

```
{% ratings item %}
```

So when I add a new post, there appears this ForeignKey field that offers to add star_ratings model first so I can't complete adding post without manually adding star_ratings model. 
[add FK img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzwIq.png)

If I'll change it to

```
class Post(models.Model):
    rating = models.ForeignKey('star_ratings.Rating', null=True)
```

then it just creates a post without a rating, and then if I change this field in this post to something(Null or other), then when I rate on the post page, there will appear a new rating with post_name so I can change it to it.

Is there any chance I could do this without so much hassle?

I mean, I can handle it with <100 posts, but if it will be >10000 posts, how is it possible to choose rating_name that equals post_name from that dropdown?
[dropdown img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH5qm.png)

Is there a solution where I can run some script in python to synchronize star_ratings__object_id with post__id since it's the same?

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to set the queryset of your model choice field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

Comment: @Johan, I don't think I have choice field anywhere? Can you expand please?

Comment: Are you using a Create/Update view to create your form? Or where are you creating your form? Perhaps add your view function and also your Rating model above. Or are you working in the admin site?

Comment: If you are working on the admin site, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581520/filtering-dropdown-values-in-django-admin